# Call a function on an object that might be undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write this in javascript:

```
if ($("#locations > tr > th").attr("id").endsWith("_5"))
```

This works fine if `$("#locations > tr > th")` isn't undefined, but if it is an error will be thrown because you can't call endsWith on undefined. Is there a way to return false if the item is undefined, or if the statement returns false? This is what I currently have, but I'm going to have to do this pretty frequently so I'd prefer a shorter way of writing it if possible.

```
var attr = $("#locations > tr > th").attr("id")
if (attr != undefined && attr.endsWith("_5") { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack would be to alternate with the empty string, on which `endsWith` can be called:

```
if (($("#locations > tr > th").attr("id") || '').endsWith('_5')) {
  // ...
}
```

If you're using Babel (which is a great idea for a reasonably professional project of reasonable size), or if you come across this in the future once browsers have implemented it, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) too:

```
if ($("#locations > tr > th").attr("id")?.endsWith('_5')) {
  //                                    ^ optional chaining
  // ...
}
```

(The `?.` will resolve to `undefined` if the `.attr('id')` doesn't exist, rather than continuing on to the `endsWith` and throwing an error)